# Combining UV maps

Tags: uv

Is there a way of combining two or more small UV maps into one larger map? I seem to recall that there was a function in 2.4x that did this (I think it was called consolidate UV's or similar) Making everything you want into one object, unwrapping and then separating everything again seems a long winded way of doing things.

Comment: [Texture Paint Plus](https://sites.google.com/site/bartiuscrouch/scripts/texture_paint_plus) sounds like it had the functionality your after.

Answer (score 8):

Ensure UV Maps are named the same prior to merge (unless you want the UV Maps to remain separate) then combine using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.

Comment: What do you mean _named the same_? I thought you cannot name more than one things with the same text? Or do you mean the same base name?

Comment: @clabe45 if seperate objects are combined (ctrl + j) then any uv maps that are "like" named in all objects will merge as a single map of the same name.

Comment: @clabe45 two things are the same level can't have identical names but UV Maps are stored per object. Two different objects can have UV Map with the same name (default behaviour, all objects are created with 'UVMap') but you can't have 2x 'UVMap' in the same object
When you merge two different objects identical UV Maps get merged properly, but differently named ones glitch out (So Objects A&B with UV Maps A&B after merge give you Object C with UV Map A & UV Map B where A map has B objects UV's destroyed and B map has A objects UV's destroyed)

Answer (score 6):

To combine the UVs you just need to combine the objects.

In order to combine the objects, select both objects and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. Which ever object is active will be used as the final object, merging the first one into it.

Upon combining the objects the UVs will also be combined, allowing you to organize as you wish without needing to re-unwrap the UVs.

Comment: This is the way I currently do things, its just that I do remember being able to do this without joining everything first. Must have been an old Addon script from 2.4x

Comment: Thought I remembered correctly. Its an old 2.49 script written by Campbell Barton called 'Auto Image Layout' Maybe it could be updated at some point. ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure, perhaps you could share a few screenshots demonstrating what you want to achieve?

To the best of my knowledge you can't combine UVs without joining objects.

Comment: I have just checked out the script with 2.49 and it appears I misunderstood it's purpose. It can only combine multiple small maps into one if those separate maps are part of a single object. It can't combine maps from separate objects. Sorry to have wasted you're time, its just that being able to do this for separate objects would be very useful for me.