# After Joining meshes lost uv map , how do I get the other to return?

Tags: mesh, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm experiencing an issue simiilar to this one
[UV mapping lost when joining mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44419/uv-mapping-lost-when-joining-mesh)

[Problem after joining meshes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30863/problem-after-joining-meshes)

though I have not been able to solve my exact issue. I had two seperate meshes, a head mesh and body, I uvwrapped them seperately (wish I hadn't). When I joined them (they had different uvmap names) i had a uvmap in slot 1, and a uvmap in slot 2. the nornmals no longer display for my head in slot2. I've been trying for hours to get the normals to return for my head. What's the trick to get this to work?

i've circled how i have two uvmaps named, and what my single combined mesh looks like, the head has no normal map displaying.

[image]
[image]

update: 
I see this... if I click one uvmap it renders if i click the other that one renders, but i cannot toggle them both on, so what does one do then?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). This thread on combining UV maps should help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/928/78972. You'll need the objects separated first, to join the UV maps into one.